Create Records in SF Based on Email Sync Using Einstein Activity Capture
We have a requirement where we need to create Account and Email(on related Opportunity) record in Salesforce, based on the Email Sync done by Einstein Activity Capture. Below are the two scenario's:-
Scenario 1
a)When we receive an email which gets sync to related Contact in Salesforce(using EAC), an automation should run in the SF backend to create a Account record(if it does not exists) and associate to the Contact record. Condition to search if the Account record already exists is the Email Domain. And if Account record already exists, then tag the Contact record to the Account.
Challenge :- The Emails Synced are not physically saved in Salesforce, so it is difficult to capture record instantly in the backend.
Scenario 2
b)When we receive an email which gets sync to related Contact in Salesforce(using EAC), an automation should run in the SF backend to identify the Email synced in Salesforce and attach a copy of the email to the related Opportunity record(similar to the way it is done in Contact record). We can ask the User to provide some kind of a identifier in the body or ask to do any similar action, if that would help.
Challenge :- The Emails Synced are not physically saved in Salesforce, so it is difficult to capture record instantly in the backend.
How can we create Account records and tag email to Opportunity records when a email sync is done using Einstein Activity Capture?

@FelixvanHove We are not able to create records in both the scenarios, how can we create Account records and tag email to Opportunity records when a email sync is done using Einstein Activity Capture?

You are potentially approaching this from the wrong direction, given Einstein Activity Capture is a fairly constrained product.
As you've stated a few times in your question, email records are not actually stored in Salesforce by EAC and hence you can't utilise those for automation. However, to answer the two parts of your question:
1. Account creation:
While the email isn't available in Salesforce, the Contact record is created and hence should be where you drive the automation from. There is no need with this requirement to utilise the emails themselves, as the Contact's email address will be synced on creation by EAC and hence can be used for the Account creation you have mentioned.
2. Associating Emails to Opportunities:
You should review how this functionality works within EAC, as per the Guidelines for Using Emails with Einstein Activity Capture article emails are automatically added to the Opportunity based on the existence of a matching Opportunity Contact Role. As long as that data exists, there is no need (and in fact as the records don't exist in Salesforce, it's not possible without replicating the data) to add any other automation on top of the out of the box functionality.
An alternative to this would be to utilise the Outlook/Gmail Integration and Sync (Outlook article here if you absolutely need to control where the emails are associated. This is a manual sync/association however, but provides the ability for users to select which records in Salesforce those emails are attached to.
